# How do I wakeup a kthread that's sleeping with ssleep so I can stop it?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

My exit function looks like this:

```c
static void __exit kMeter_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "kMeter: Requesting thread stop\n");
    if (task)
        kthread_stop(task);

    printk(KERN_INFO "kMeter: Leaving Kernel Module\n");
}
```

My thread function looks like this:

```c
static int mainTask(void* data)
{
    bool allDone;
    allow_signal(SIGKILL);
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    while (!kthread_should_stop())
    {
        set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
        allDone = mainLoop();
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        if (allDone)
            msleep_interruptible(poll_interval*1000);
        else
            usleep_range(TICK_TIME, TICK_TIME+100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I call `rmmod` the thread doesn't wake up from the sleep, so I'm stuck there until the timeout happens.  Depending on settings, that timeout could be as long as 5 minutes.  I thought `kthread_stop()` was supposed to wakeup the associated thread, and I thought `msleep_interruptible` was suposed to allow that wakeup to happen.  What am I missing?

Comment: So, which branch is executed, `msleep_interruptible` or `usleep_range`? The first one is interruptible, but the second isn't. BTW, both functions set task's state by themselves, no needs to do that manually (remove calls to `set_current_state()`).

Comment: The usleep_range only lasts a few hundred ms, so it's not that which is causing this.  the poll_interval value (expressed in seconds) can be as high as 300 (which is 5 minutes).  It simply doesn't exit until the time is expired even though it's "interruptible" and I called kthread_stop().

Comment: Hmm, I am unsure, but according to source of [msleep_interruptible](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timer.c#L1683), it looks like `kthread_stop()` will not break its cycle `while (timeout && !signal_pending(current))`. While stopping awakes kthread, it is not counted as a *signal*. You need to elaborate your sleep function and check `kthread_should_stop()` in it. You may use `schedule_timeout(timeout)` in you implementation: waiting in this function is interrupted by `kthread_stop()`.

Comment: `schedule_timeout()` seems to have fixed the issue.  I really don't understand why though as it seems that `msleep_interruptible` just eventually calls `schedule_timeout` anyway.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, `kthread_stop()` breaks waiting in `schedule_timeout`, but doesn't break cycle while `(timeout && !signal_pending(current))`, which is used by `msleep_interruptible` for repeat waiting in case of spurious wakeups.